# Asp.Net 4.0 Profiling on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, profiling

New to both Asp.Net 4.0 and IIS7 deployment.

I am having a runtime problem with my application. Basically certain pages are not loading, also looks like a memory issue related to certain calls etc.

What are some of the tools and techniques for profiling/debugging Asp.net 4.0 when deployed on iis7. I am just looking for a way to get the BIG picture and the drill down to smaller level.

Is it suggested that any profiling of value take place in VS2010?

Answer (score 0):

You can use iis7 failed request logs to track which handler is causing pages to fail out. Using this approach, you can narrow down where the issue is happening, and then use asp.net page level tracking and exception stack traces in your event log to solve the problem. Also, good logging in your global.asax application_error method is always recommended.